# undefined javascript func when moving from view to script file

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5

This code works fine if the script is inside the view, but if I move it to a custom script file it gives error saying that the "simpleFunc()" is undefined. I'm using VS 2013 MVC 5 and there is already a reference to the script file in the BundleConfig.

```
  bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/custom").Include(
                     "~/Scripts/Custom/custom.js"));
```

and this to the _layout view:
      @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/custom")

```
<div>
    <button type="button" onclick="simpleFunc()">Button</button>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    <script type="text/javascript">

    function simpleFunc() {
        alert("Hello from simpleFunc");
    }
</script>
}
```

This is the script file custom.js:

```
function simpleFunc() {
    alert("Hello from simpleFunc from custom script");
}
```

I've also added the below line in the view, but it didn't work :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/Custom/custom.js"></script>
```

Comment: Are you seeing any other errors at the console in your browser's dev tools? That sounds like maybe the script isn't loading. Is there any other code in `custom.js`? A parse error anywhere in that file could prevent `simpleFunc` from being available also.

Comment: @Dave Ward: It says (in the VS Error List) JsHint(WO98): 'simpleFunc' is defined but never used

Comment: Are you certain the view actually has the @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/custom") statement? Use the browser's dev toolbar to check the Network tab and see if it is indeed downloading the bundle/script.

Comment: If you're just getting a JsHint message in the error list, that's not necessarily indicating a critical issue. When you said originally that you were getting the error about `SimpleFunc()` being undefined, was that the JsHint message or something you're seeing in the browser when you try to click the button?